Creating a Form with a Custom Template
One of the requirements for my APEX application is the ability to have a form with a dynamic amount of entries and the ability to filter/search for a specific entries.  Since the out of box form region requires a form entry to correspond to a database column, accomplishing this task is quite difficult.
It seems to me that the best option would be to create a custom template that looks and interacts just like a form so that each entry would correspond to a row instead of a column, which would be much more easy to deal with.  Since all of the entries correspond to rows in this instance, the filtering/searching would be much easier and the total entries at any given time could be changed by a non-developer pretty easily if needed.
So far my custom template uses the following row template:


<div class="t-Form-fieldContainer t-Form-fieldContainer--floatingLabel t-Form-fieldContainer--preTextBlock t-Form-fieldContainer--postTextBlock lto1556169442680158453_0 apex-item-wrapper apex-item-wrapper--select-list js-show-label" id="P200_#ID#_CONTAINER">
  <span class="t-Form-itemText t-Form-itemText--pre">
            <b>#PRE_TEXT_ID#</b>
        </span>
  <div class="t-Form-labelContainer">
    <label for="P200_#ID#" id="P200_#ID#_LABEL" class="t-Form-label">#NAME#</label>
  </div>
  <div class="t-Form-inputContainer">
    <div class="t-Form-itemWrapper">
      <select id="P200_#ID#" name="P200_#ID#" class="selectlist apex-item-select" data-native-menu="false" size="1" style="background-color: #BACKGROUND_COLOR#;">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="1">Yes</option>
        <option value="3">No, PRT Action!</option>
        <option value="4" selected="selected">No, Escalation</option>
        <option value="5">N/A</option>
      </select>
      <span class="t-Form-itemText t-Form-itemText--post">
                    <a href="#POST_TEXT_LINK#" class="#POST_TEXT_ICON#"></a>
                </span>
    </div>
    <span id="P200_#ID#_error_placeholder" class="a-Form-error" data-template-id="1548925300217985001_ET"></span>
  </div>
</div>



This spits out a "form" that looks exactly how I need it to look but there are two main issues I am running into from fully implementing it:

The select lists that are being created as entries can't be hard coded into the template.  My initial thought was to build the <option value="x">blah blah</option> lines within the source query of my classic report, but it negatively effects the readability of the region. I was wondering if there was an alternative method that allowed some of the "processing" to be done within the template
When a user changes one of the select lists at run time, I need to process some data.  I don't know how to access what the select lists created from this query contain or how to access the #ID# for a select list when it gets changed.

Any help with this issue, or recommendations for a completely different alternative that meets my requirements would be greatly appreciated.

"a form entry to correspond to a database column". That is not true, you can map a page item to anything. You don't need to use the native form but can write your own from scratch with pl/sql code in page processes (this is not an answer to your question)

May you don't need to create your own Template. What you need to do is manipulate your source of region to use PIVOTING query. then customize the Form - Automatic Row Processing (DML) process with target type PL/SQL Code that use looping during processing.

I had thought of this before but I reach the character limit in the "pivot columns" clause as the form is a few hundred entries long
